# Problem of iterating over the dataloader in PyTorch Geometric

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

When iterating over the data loader, i.e., `for item in train_loader`, I got the error message

```
RuntimeError: Expected a 'mps:0' generator device but found 'mps'
```

The following is my code when defining the dataloader:

```
device = torch.device('mps')
torch.set_default_device(device)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, generator=torch.Generator(device=device))
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=100, shuffle=False, generator=torch.Generator(device=device))
```

I have tried to set

```
device = torch.device('mps:0')
```

and

```
generator=torch.Generator(device='mps:0')
```

but neither of them works.